# Bash Function in .profile is not running SimpleHTTPServer - file not found

Tags: python, bash, function, profile, simplehttpserver

So I have a simple bash function stored in ~/.profile as follows:

`function testingServer() {
        local port="${1:-8000}"
        python SimpleHTTPServer "$port"
        open "http://localhost:${port}/"
}`

But when I run the function, it gives me this error:

`python: can't open file 'SimpleHTTPServer': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Which to me seems strange, since everything works fine when I run the command longhand like this:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

Any clue as to what I can do to try to chase this down?

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you just missing the `-m` argument when you invoke Python? Add that in and it should work.

```
function testingServer() {
    local port="${1:-8000}"
    python -m SimpleHTTPServer "$port"
    open "http://localhost:${port}/"
}
```

It's correct that `SimpleHTTPServer` is not a file (especially not one in your local directory). But the `-m` indicates it's a module, and therefore how/where to find it.

Whether this is precisely what you want/need to do from a testing perspective is another matter. But at least you can get rid of the `can't open file` error.

Comment: So even with the -m added in to the function, I still have the same result: python: can't open file 'SimpleHTTPServer': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I verified that this runs on my system just fine. So, your python executable is apparently not seeing the proper module. Do you set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before invoking this function? If not, try that. Also try inserting `which python` and `python --version` both in the `.profile` and at the command line. Make sure they point to the same rev of Python.